# ALTER USER WITH LOGIN throws error "Windows NT user or group not found"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, logins

Attempting to deprecate the procedure `sp_change_users_login` as [recommended by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-change-users-login-transact-sql). I tried using:

```
ALTER USER UserName WITH LOGIN = UserName
```

as [demonstrated here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/do-you-still-use-sp_change_users_login/).  This results in the error

> Msg 15401, Level 16, State 2, Line 3458
>   Windows NT user or group 'UserName' not found. Check the name again.

UserName is both the user and the SQL login.  Surely I am missing something simple but I cannot see what it is.

I had 3 names that failed and one does not have a login, but the other 2 do have logins.  I can see the login and users in the Object Explorer.  However if I open the login properties the user is not assigned to the target database.  If I manually check the db box it works, but the point is that I am trying to clear up any orphaned users in my target database using SQL.

Answer (score 3):

This error will happen if the login you are attempting to use does not exist.

Example:

```
CREATE LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = '131fEWF$#@FR$#Vverf';
CREATE LOGIN username2 WITH PASSWORD = '131fEWF$#@FR$#Vverf';

USE tempdb;
CREATE USER username FOR LOGIN username;

ALTER USER username WITH LOGIN = username2; /*Successful*/

DROP LOGIN username;

ALTER USER username WITH LOGIN = username; /*Unsuccessful*/
```

You should check to ensure that the login was not removed prior to your attempt to run the `ALTER USER` command.